# Why may I workaround List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Cat> by using <? extends Animal>?

Tags: java, generics

My initial question was:
Why does the second creation fail?
This question was marked as already answered with the hint to change the question so it's something new. I will do so now

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
List<Animal> list2 = new ArrayList<Cat>();
```

I understand that now. It is because later on you would use `list2` as List of Animals. As soon as you would add a Dog, we would have a ClassCastException or similar. This is a situation that should be eliminated by using generics and thus is unacceptable else the generics implementation would be useless.

As in one of the comments is stated this should work:

```
List<? extends Animal> list3 = new ArrayList<Cat>();
```

Then why suddenly is the above explained problem gone?

Comment: In short `List<Object> list2` would allow you to add *any* object, for instance Integer, Boolean, Cat, but `new ArrayList<String>()` allows only Strings (or it subtypes if they could exist).

Comment: TL;DR: a `List<String>` isn't a `List<Object>` because you can add an `Object` to the latter but not the former.

Comment: Ahhh. now I understand. The receiving code would believe the List accepts everything and so break as soon as it does not add a String. We would produce a situation which we wanted to eliminate through generics.

Comment: @JPT but you could declare `List<? extends Object> list2` (or, equivalently, `List<?> list2`), since the compiler would then prevent you adding anything except literal `null` to that list.